# My AVD emulator doesn't get loaded at Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-virtual-device, launching

I usually develop my android tests at Windows using the Eclipse IDE. But now that I am needing to do the same at Ubuntu, for some unknown reason the emulator isn't getting loaded, but is getting frozen at the android launching screen. It doesn't show any error message, just get stopped on that screen(I am waiting for more than 2 hours), I don't know why. I am using the Ubuntu 12.04 Precise-Pangolin, and trying to launch the Android 2.2(Froyo) at emulator.

Comment: Need more info. What version of Ubuntu are you using? What version of the SDK, what's the emulator image you are trying to load?

Comment: I am using the 12.04 precise-pangolin, and trying to launch the android 2.2(Froyo).

Comment: works fine for me, have you tried waiting for it to load up? it usually takes some time.

Comment: Oh guy, i 'm waiting here for 1 hour focusing on the AVD window. At the Windows system i had to wait just for something like 10 minutes for fist time, and after less than 5.

Comment: Anyone there to help me?

Comment: When you launched the emulator from the command line with the `-version` switch, what error messages, etc. appeared?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your hardware and what version of android you are using, it can take a long time. Honeycomb+ for me took over an hour on my somewhat high end laptop the first time it booted, I thought it had frozen.

Comment: Right, but I waited for 2 hours but the emulator didn't launch. However, at the Windows(XP) OS I had to wait just for 10 minutes in my first launch, and, after, less than 5 minutes.